# How to setup separate projectName/gitolite-admin.git configuration repositories with Gitolite?

Tags: ssh, gitolite, git

I want to setup a [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) based installation for hosting git repositories in a small organization for a limited set of projects (100 projects at most, probably less than 30) with repositories under directories like

```
gitolite@hostname:some_project/
gitolite@hostname:project_teletubby/
```

I will use an LDAP-backed SSH server public-key based authentication so I don't need Gitolite to manage authentication keys.

Instead of using a single configuration repository (`gitolite@hostname:gitolite-admin.git`) how can I allow project managers to use their own configuration repositories (e.g. `gitolite@hostname:projectName/gitolite-admin.git`) to manage everything beneath their `projectName/` path without read and write access to configurations of other projects?

Comment: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#deleg

Comment: Unfortunately, using the Gitolite `subconf` command is not an option, because project managers will still have read access to the whole `gitolite@hostname:gitolite-admin.git` repository and can read the configurations of other projects as well.

Comment: Then Gitolite is the wrong tool for you.

Comment: @SvW I still think it may be possible by writing some wrapper between `.ssh/authorized_keys` and Gitolite which rewrites the repository name in `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` and then somehow calls `gitolite-shell`.

Comment: Might be, but it's likely not supported. Why don't use a tool that fits your requirements from the start instead of trying to coax another to do something it's not supposed to do?